# Translation Name Should be Unique In Soanata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am working in sonata admin.

I have master table and translation table.

```
Master Table:

id
phonecode
status

Translation Table : 

id
master_id
name
language_code
status
```

I am done unique validation of phonecode using UniqueEntity by unique=true.

Now i want same kind of thing for translation table for column "name" , its entity is different but joined.

How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can anyone help me for this question ?